# Getting "Whitelabel Error Page" when I ran a brand new spring boot project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am new to Spring Boot. I initialized a Spring project using Spring Initializr as follows (Stack Overflow prohibits me to include pictures because I'm new, all links below are actually pictures, sorry for the inconvenience):
[My Spring Initializer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bOXpW.jpg)

Then I ran the Spring project without editing one line of code, here's the file I ran:
[Main Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GI6y5.jpg)

Here is my console after running RestfulWebServicesApplication.java: [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w9Rpv.jpg)

But when I go to localhost:8080, I ran into the [Whitelabel Error Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6FK5.jpg)

Could anybody help me with this problem? Thank you!

Comment: There is no problem. That is default Spring's error page. That means everything is working.

Comment: As Mr Robot said, that's the default error page. As to why you got it, it tells you: 404, not found. You don't have any content such as a RestController in your app.

Comment: Thank you so much Mr. Robot and SledgeHammer, after adding a controller, the error is gone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the default error that gets thrown when you haven't mapped any URL to its method. You got 404 because there is no Controller in your app as of now.

Just the fact that you are seeing this page means your Spring-boot project was configured successfully and you can continue with your project.

Comment: Thank you so much, as I created a controller, the error is gone and everything looks fine

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `index.html` file?? What SpringBoot will show on UI when you do not have index file.

Comment: Thank you so much, including an index.html file in src/main/resources/static does solve the problem!